# gcc doesn't find output fine and therefore cannot compile my c program (vscode)

Tags: linux, compiling, c, gcc, visual-studio-code

As the title suggests it is the output file it cannot find, not sure why this is an issue here is my c_cpp_properties.json:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "~/edu/doa/code_base/datastructures-v1.0.13.0/include"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c99",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": [
                "-Wall"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

here is my tasks.json:

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "C/C++: gcc build int_array_1d_mwe with DoA code base options",
        "command": "/usr/bin/gcc",
        "args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-std=c99",
            "-Wall",
            "-I",
            "~/edu/doa/code_base/datastructures-v1.0.13.0/include/", //Deklarationer
            "~/../../usr/include/",
            "-g",
            //"${workspaceFolder}/tabletest-1.9.c",
            "${workspaceFolder}/graph2.c", //Din_fil.c
            "~/edu/doa/code_base/datastructures-v1.0.13.0/src/dlist/dlist.c", //Definitioner
            "/home/manfred/edu/doa/code_base/datastructures-v1.0.13.0/src/array_1d/array_1d.c",
            "-o",
            "${workspaceFolder}/outputfile" //Output
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "Customized for int_array_1d_mwe and DoA code base 1.0.13.0."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

here is the output when i run the program (Debug anyway):
[image]

here is the error page when i click Show Errors after failed compilation:
[image]

here is the 'Debug anyway' popup i get:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `task.json` file, you have `-I` followed by a directory path.  This seems ok, but then you have another directory path, `~/../../usr/include/`, before the `-g` debug option.  The compiler would see the second directory path and, since it's not an argument to any option, would try to use it in the compilation as if it was a source file.  A diagnostic message mentions this directory path in your debug output.

What's missing is another `-I` option before the second directory path.

Alternatively, since `~/../../usr/include/` is probably the same as `/usr/include` (unless your home directory is lower down in the file hierarchy than usual on a Linux system), which would likely be searched by default, you may instead want to remove the mentioning of that path in the JSON task specification.

I'm not a VSCode user and have never seen these JSON files before. I'm just looking at the error messages and inferring what must have happened and why.